# NSDateformatter not working in IOS 7.0.4

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, nsdateformatter

I was using NSDateformatter for parsing a date. It was working fine til I updated to iOS 7.0.4. But since the update I am getting a nil value,

This is the date I am trying to parse

```
11/20/2013 3:30:05 PM
```

Below is the code for the same

```
NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter1 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
dateFormatter1.dateFormat = @"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a";
[dateFormatter1 setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
NSDate *date = [dateFormatter1 dateFromString:[items objectAtIndex:2]];
```

But I am getting nil as the date.

How can I make this work in IOS 7.0.4?

Comment: Are you sure the value for [items objectAtIndex:2] is correct. I tried the code too on iOS 7 simulator and it works fine for me.

Comment: Are you sure you still have something in `[items objectAtIndex:2]`?

Comment: Right, you need to give us example text of `[items objectAtIndex:2]`

Comment: Thanks for your response. In fact the same code works fine in IOS 7.0.2 . I am having this issue only with IOS 7.0.4 .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your date is localized, but you are using the device its locale.
But the AM/PM may be different in other locales.

```
-(void)dateTest {
    NSString *inputDate = @"11/20/2013 3:30:05 PM";
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter1 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    dateFormatter1.dateFormat = @"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a";
    [dateFormatter1 setLocale:[[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US_POSIX"]];
    NSDate *date = [dateFormatter1 dateFromString:inputDate];
    NSLog(@"date: %@", date); //OUTPUT date: 2013-11-20 15:30:05 +0000
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Can you post what string is stored in [items objectAtIndex:2]?
I try it and it works fine for me:

```
-(void)dateTest
{
    NSString *inputDate = @"11/20/2013 3:30:05 PM";
    NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter1 = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    dateFormatter1.dateFormat = @"MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss a";
    [dateFormatter1 setLocale:[NSLocale currentLocale]];
    NSDate *date = [dateFormatter1 dateFromString:inputDate];
    NSLog(@"date: %@", date); //OUTPUT date: 2013-11-20 15:30:05 +0000
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response. In fact the same code works fine in IOS 7.0.2 . I am having this issue only with IOS 7.0.4 . I can confirm that the [items objectAtIndex:2] has the same date.

Answer (score 0):

If it is displaying a different hour you may need to set the default timezone (this happens only after ios7)

```
[dateFormat setTimeZone:[NSTimeZone timeZoneWithAbbreviation:@"GMT"]];
```

it seems that the default timezone is the one the device has, so if you no specify the default timezone you might get strange results. Prior to ios7 it was always GMT.